# conexion via ssh with ubuntu 18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ovh

I connect via ssh to an OVH hosting, I manage to connect but the problem is that I cannot execute any ubuntu command when I try to install ruby ​​and rails on my server.
I am new to ssh ...

```
formasm@cloudweb-ssh:~ $ sudo su
-bash: sudo: command not found
formasm@cloudweb-ssh:~ $ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
formasm@cloudweb-ssh:~ $ sudo apt-get update
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried installing sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OVH Hosting `Cloud Web` offers, you don't have access to the `sudo` command nor to the `root` user: as this is a managed offer, you don't have the administrator rights.

However, it's totally possible to install `Ruby on Rails`, as Cloud Web provide dependency manager for different languages (`gem` and `bundle` for Ruby; `npm` and `yarn` for NodeJS etc.).

To install `Ruby on Rails` on OVH's `Cloud Web`:

```sh
jeanmim@cloudweb-ssh:~ $ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ruby2.6/bin:~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin
jeanmim@cloudweb-ssh:~ $ export GEM_HOME=~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0

jeanmim@cloudweb-ssh:~ $ gem install rails --user --no-doc
Fetching thread_safe-0.3.6.gem
Fetching concurrent-ruby-1.1.6.gem
Fetching i18n-1.8.2.gem
Fetching zeitwerk-2.3.0.gem
....

jeanmim@cloudweb-ssh:~ $ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 12.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
....
```

You can find a documentation here about how to install a Ruby app on a `Cloud Web` hosting: https://docs.ovh.com/fr/cloud-web/installer-camaleon-cloud-web/ (in french only from what I can see)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, the project was urgently needed and I had to change the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

What verison of ubuntu is it running 
you can find out what your version is using 
`lsb_release -a`

you will get a output like this

```
steve@mineblox:~# lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

steve@mineblox:~#
```

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: do you have acces to `su -` 
becous you can install sudo when you have acces to root
using `apt-get install sudo`

Comment: Unfortunately i can't even log in as root

Comment: @danisandrios 
then i got realy sad news for  you becous you cant install sudo or have super user permisions

Comment: @steve@minebox, Thank you for your help, I will try to request a new root password from ovh

Answer (score 0):

My ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```